# How to connect a Node.js TCP-client in container A to a TCP-server in container B with Docker Compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, tcp, docker-compose

I am trying to connect a TCP-client in container A to a TCP-server in container B. Running docker-compose up results in a ECONNREFUSED error on the client side. 为什么呢？

The TCP-client looks like this:

```
   var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    // client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

The TCP-client Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

ADD package.json /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

CMD npm start
```

The TCP-server looks like this:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337);
```

The TCP-server Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

ADD package.json /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

CMD npm start
```

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  tcpclient:
    build: ./tcpclient
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - tcpserver
  tcpserver:
    build: ./tcpserver
    ports:
      - "8001:1337"
```

The connection error looks like this:

```
tcpclient_1  | > http-service@1.0.0 start /app
tcpclient_1  | > node tcpclient.js
tcpclient_1  |
tcpclient_1  | events.js:137
tcpclient_1  |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
tcpclient_1  |       ^
tcpclient_1  |
tcpclient_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
tcpclient_1  |     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
tcpclient_1  |     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
tcpclient_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1194:14)
tcpclient_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 127.0.0.1 will point to the localhost of your container, not to the localhost of your host. Try to connect using tcpserver:1337 instead of 127.0.0.1. Docker compose will deploy those containers by default in the same network which means they can resolve eachother by using servicename

Comment: Okay adding 'tcpserver' as host worked like magic. Thank you!

Comment: Right now, the client connects to the server:

`tcpclient_1  |
tcpclient_1  | > http-service@1.0.0 start /app
tcpclient_1  | > node tcpclient.js
tcpclient_1  |
tcpclient_1  | Connected` 

However, after connecting, the client does not receive data. The code can be seen here: https://github.com/wassbeer/docker/tree/networking-in-compose

Comment: I'm not a node developer, but when I uncomment client.destroy();, it seems to be destroyed and it prints "connection closed" after receiving the data but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem turned out to be `docker-compose up` does not log the entire output in the Docker Toolbox. When running `docker-compose logs --follow tcpclient` I can see the entire server-client communication.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems here.
I'm not sure *localhost* from a container will be in the same interface than your host. Moreover, the port bound is 8001. But, I would recomand another approach:

Using `link` you can reference other containers hosts with their name.
I would try to:

1) Add in `tcpclient` container definition:

    `links:
      - tcpserver`

2) Keep 1337:1337 in tcp server (why is client exposing a TCP port btw ?)
3) use `client.connect(1337, 'tcpserver', function(...){...}`

Comment: 1) Thank you, adding 'tcpserver' as HOST to the client.connect(1337, ....) makes the client connect! 

2) Adding the link does not seem to change the behaviour. Without it works as well.

3) After connection, the client does not receive data, or does not log this. Any clue why it does connect but does not receive data? Thank you.